# Movement and collision function

Tags: python, performance, pygame, collision

I just want this code optimized to the max and I don't mind knowing if the optimization is pretty much at the max already or if I am doing movement and collision wrong. My game is a 2d Minecraft style game so it will have a lot of `other_rects`. Hopefully my code is easy to read.

### Code:

```
def move(rect, movement, other_rects): # move one axis at a time, returns moved rect and info on collisions
    collisions = [0, 0, 0, 0] # left, right, up, down

    if movement.x:
        rect.x += movement.x
        if movement.x < 0:
            for tile in [tile for tile in other_rects if rect.colliderect(tile)]:
                rect.left = tile.right
                collisions[0] = 1
        else:
            for tile in [tile for tile in other_rects if rect.colliderect(tile)]:
                rect.right = tile.left
                collisions[1] = 1

    if movement.y:
        rect.y += movement.y
        if movement.y < 0:
            for tile in [tile for tile in other_rects if rect.colliderect(tile)]:
                rect.top = tile.bottom
                collisions[2] = 1
        else:
            for tile in [tile for tile in other_rects if rect.colliderect(tile)]:
                rect.bottom = tile.top
                collisions[3] = 1

    return rect, collisions
```

### Code for testing:

```
import pygame
import pygame.math

pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption('Physics')
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500),0,32)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

player = pygame.Rect(100,100,40,80)
tiles = [pygame.Rect(200,350,50,50),pygame.Rect(260,320,50,50)] # could be made bigger
speed = 5

def move(rect, movement, other_rects):
    ... # put move function here

while 1:
    movement = pygame.math.Vector2(0)

    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_a] and not keys[pygame.K_d]:
        movement.x -= speed
    if keys[pygame.K_d] and not keys[pygame.K_a]:
        movement.x += speed
    if keys[pygame.K_w] and not keys[pygame.K_s]:
        movement.y -= speed
    if keys[pygame.K_s] and not keys[pygame.K_w]:
        movement.y += speed

    player = move(player,movement,tiles)[0]

    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,(255,255,255),player)
    for tile in tiles:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,(255,0,0),tile)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: Since you're filtering values based on what's returned when you pass them to a function, you could use filter instead of list comps: `for tile in filter(rect.colliderect, other_rects):`

Comment: It looks like the branches of the `if movement.x < 0:` statement are reversed. The way all the `for tile...` loops are coded, the rect sides are set based on the last colliding tile, rather than the closest tile in that direction.

Comment: @my_stack_exchange_account is that faster? If so thank you!

Comment: @Reinderien The test data could be just a list of rects, a rect to move, and a movement amount. Should I post some test data and code to apply it?

Comment: I have posted some test code. Thanks for your advice everyone. :)

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @Mast I understand, reinderein didn't answer my question, but I found some of his methods useful. If he can give me a working python script (that can be run in my version of python, 3.8.10), I will accept. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone who has helped me (in the end it was mainly [@Reinderien](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/25834/reinderien)). Taking bits and pieces of advice I have put together an optimized (most likely not fully) 'movement and collision function'.

## Reveiwed code

```
import pygame
import pygame.math

pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption('Physics')
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500),0,32)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

player = pygame.Rect(100,100,40,80)
tiles = [pygame.Rect(200,350,50,50),pygame.Rect(260,320,50,50)]
speed = 5

def move(rect, movement, other_rects): # move one axis at a time, returns info on collisions
    collisions = [0, 0, 0, 0] # left, right, up, down

    if movement.x:
        rect.x += movement.x
        collided_with = [other_rects[i] for i in rect.collidelistall(other_rects)]
        if collided_with:
            if movement.x < 0:
                rect.left = max(tile.right for tile in collided_with)
                collisions[0] = 1
            else:
                rect.right = min(tile.left for tile in collided_with)
                collisions[1] = 1

    if movement.y:
        rect.y += movement.y
        collided_with = [other_rects[i] for i in rect.collidelistall(other_rects)]
        if collided_with:
            if movement.y < 0:
                rect.top = max(tile.bottom for tile in collided_with)
                collisions[2] = 1
            else:
                rect.bottom = min(tile.top for tile in collided_with)
                collisions[3] = 1

    return collisions


while 1:
    movement = pygame.math.Vector2(0)

    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_a] and not keys[pygame.K_d]:
        movement.x -= speed
    if keys[pygame.K_d] and not keys[pygame.K_a]:
        movement.x += speed
    if keys[pygame.K_w] and not keys[pygame.K_s]:
        movement.y -= speed
    if keys[pygame.K_s] and not keys[pygame.K_w]:
        movement.y += speed

    move(player,movement,tiles)

    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,(255,255,255),player)
    for tile in tiles:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,(255,0,0),tile)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

## Optimizations

1 - Used `collidelistall` instead of `colliderect`, avoids checking for each individual `rect`. [@Reinderien](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/25834/reinderien)

2 - Used `min` and `max` functions to correctly uncollide, also avoids looping through the list of collisions. [@Reinderien](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/25834/reinderien)

3 - Removed the `rect` from `return rect, collisions` as the function is already modifying the `rect`. [@Reinderien](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/25834/reinderien)

Answer (score 3):

First understand that your collision algorithm isn't correct. This is evident by either making the player travel speed higher or making the object coordinates closer; you can quite easily end up with a situation like this:

[image: overlap]

That's because you assign the collided edge unconditionally. There is no one correct algorithm; you could:

- Stop the player along their vector of travel at the first collided object, which would work but would not allow for "glancing blows" redirecting diagonal to horizontal/vertical travel
- Undo the minimum amount of travel in each axis necessary to de-collide all objects; this does allow for "glancing blows" and is what I demonstrate below

A first pass that un-breaks this, and makes better use of `collidelistall`, looks like:

```
from typing import Sequence

from pygame import Vector2, Rect
import pygame


SPEED = 5


def manhattan(vector: tuple[int, int]) -> int:
    x, y = vector
    return abs(x) + abs(y)


def move(player: Rect, movement: Vector2, others: Sequence[Rect]) -> Rect:
    if not movement:  # truthy means any nonzero dimension
        return player

    player = Rect(
        player.left + movement.x, player.top + movement.y,
        player.width, player.height,
    )
    
    for i in player.collidelistall(others):
        tile = others[i]

        # There are four directions, each with its own distance, to de-collide the player.
        deltas = (
            (min(0, tile.left - player.right), 0),
            (max(0, tile.right - player.left), 0),
            (0, min(0, tile.top - player.bottom)),
            (0, max(0, tile.bottom - player.top)),
        )
        # Choose the direction with the lowest necessary Manhattan norm.
        dx, dy = min(deltas, key=manhattan)
        player.left += dx
        player.top += dy

    return player


def get_movement() -> Vector2:
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    x = 0
    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        x -= SPEED
    if keys[pygame.K_d]:
        x += SPEED

    y = 0
    if keys[pygame.K_w]:
        y -= SPEED
    if keys[pygame.K_s]:
        y += SPEED

    return pygame.math.Vector2(x, y)


def main() -> None:
    pygame.init()

    try:
        pygame.display.set_caption('Physics')
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500), 0, 32)
        clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        player = Rect(100, 100, 40, 80)
        tiles = (Rect(200, 350, 50, 50), Rect(260, 346, 50, 50))  # could be made bigger

        while not any(e.type == pygame.QUIT for e in pygame.event.get()):
            movement = get_movement()
            player = move(player, movement, tiles)

            screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), player)
            for tile in tiles:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), tile)

            pygame.display.update()
            clock.tick(60)
    finally:
        pygame.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

For small object lists this will be enough. For a huge object collection this will still be inefficient and you need to use a spatial indexing data structure like a [quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree). There is no built-in support for this in pygame, but there are examples floating around on the internet.

Comment: For back-compatibility, replace `tuple[int, int]` with `Tuple[int, int]`, importing that symbol from `typing`

Comment: sorry, it doesn't work properly, [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51McP.png)

Comment: I cannot reproduce the behaviour you see, and in the end you own this code, not me. You're going to need to debug it.

Comment: The rects are in this pos `tiles = (Rect(200, 350, 50, 50), Rect(280, 330, 50, 50))` then try enter in the top. I am going to post my own answer, sorry. Thanks for all your help, I am going to use some of your tricks like `collidelistall`, `max` and `min`.